# Python OpenCV Stereo Calibrate Object Points

Tags: python, opencv, stereoscopy

I am really having a hard time to grasp this thing, I'm only a beginner in python, and I cannot find an explanation to this code.

```
# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
```

the original is that, 9 is 7. I assumed that 9 and 6 are the inner corners of the columns and rows of the chessboard pattern respectively. (so my chessboard is really 10x7)

Now, I know the size of the square on the chessboard, what i cannot figure out is where to put it there.

As every iteration on every image, the code I found just do this:

```
objpoints.append(objp)
```

And I can see, it's always pushing the same object again and again.

Two Questions:
how does `objpoints.append(objp)` on every iteration make a difference?

how can i specify in the code, the square size? where should i put it?

I know that object points are the 3d points of each squares in the chessboard, that's why im very confused it's not even manipulated in each iteration.

Thanks!

EDIT:
My code for stereocalib: http://pastebin.com/pw5n3pme

(It is just a modified version of individual camera calibration)

Comment: You should link the whole code, if you want a complete answer and understand what it does. I will try to answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are working with [this code](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html) or a similar one.

*First question*

> how does objpoints.append(objp) on every iteration make a difference?
>   It doesn't. From the line you posted, look at this

```
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
```

Here it is calculating the disposition of the chessboard corners, which, in a certain chessboard, are always the same. Every iteration you find different imgpoints in your camera **for the same points in the chessboard**.

If the were not the same points, you could not perform the calibration

*Second question*

> how can i specify in the code, the square size? where should i put it?

in the tutorial I posted, for Python and OpenCV, you should not specify the square size. It is mono-calibration, so square size is related only to scale factor, (quite) useless in mono camera. You will obtain a correct camera matrix with an undefined (or maybe equal to 1) scale factor.

If you have a different code (e.g stereo calibration), post it and I will try to find where the square dimension has to be put.

Comment: thank you for answer @marcoresk here is the pastebin of my stereocalib.py

http://pastebin.com/pw5n3pme

there, i used the individually calibrated matrices for left and right cameras. it worked for me rather than calibrating the two cameras at the same time.

Comment: in the stereocalib, i just copied the code you linked, and did it for the two cameras at once and just used stereoCalibrate method instead of the cameraalibrate

Comment: @WreighChristianSantos that code was only a tutorial. In order to insert the size of squares you have to use it with objp. Read [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310210/camera-calibration-with-opencv-how-to-adjust-chessboard-square-size)

Comment: thank you, i will try this, by the way, my code for stereocalib is right? right? lol. thanks man, much appreciated!

Comment: pardon me but i dont understand the answer there. where exactly should i put the size. i dont really know much about those numpy functions

Comment: I have to make a try to soy it for sure, but try, after the line with objp, something like np.dot(size,objp) (you have to multiply your grid for the size factor, as explained in the answer). Your code should be right as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

I am also doing stereo camera calibration in Python and OpenCV and I know the answer to your second question (as 1st is already answered).

> how can i specify in the code, the square size? where should i put it?

Here, if you have your square size assume 30 mm then multiply this value with `objp[:,:2]`. Like this

```
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)*30 # 30 mm size of square
```

As `objp[:,:2]` is a set of points of checkboard corners given as (0,0),(0,1), (0,2) ....(8,5). (0,0) point is the left upper most square corner  and (8,5) is right lowest square corner. In this case, these point have no unit but if we multiply these values with square size (for example 30 mm), then these will become (0,0),(0,30), .....(240,150) which are the real world units. Your translation vector will be in *mm units* in this case.